# Why output is difference? Why the data can change it self?

Tags: java

That is my code. I want to load data from file and handle it in code. I am being confused in my output. The data can change it self. That is the method main in main class. There is a code print(i); this code give wrong output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList();
    ar.add(0);
    ar.add(2);
    ar.add(4);

    Data ds = new Data();
    ds.loadDataSet(new Loader(), ar);
    System.out.println("in main class");
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.size(); i++) {
        ds.print(i);   //give wrong output
    }
 }
```

Main method call **data.class**. This class is to handling and arrange the data. In method loadDataSet() there is a code print(i); and this is give true output.

```
public class Data {

private String[] attributeName;
private Instance[] setOfInstance;

public void loadDataSet(Loader loader, ArrayList<Integer> attributeIndex) {  

    System.out.println("inside data.class");     

    setOfInstance = new Instance[loader.dataSize()];
    double[] value = new double[attributeIndex.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < setOfInstance.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
            value[j] = loader.getValue(i, attributeIndex.get(j));
        }
        setOfInstance[i] = new Instance(loader.getTupleName(i), value);

        print(i);   //give true output
    }
}

public void print(int i) {
    double db[] = getInstance(i).getAllAttributeValue();
    System.out.print(getInstance(i).getInstaceName()+ "--");
    for (int j =0; j < db.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(db[j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public Instance getInstance(int index) {
    return setOfInstance[index];
}

public int size() {
    return setOfInstance.length;
}
}
```

That is **Instance.class** to handle the instance data.

```
public class Instance {

private String name;
private double[] attributeValue;

public Instance(String name, double[] attributeValue) {
    this.name = name;
    this.attributeValue = attributeValue;
}

public String getInstaceName() {
    return name;
}

public double[] getAllAttributeValue() {
    return attributeValue;
}

}
```

That is **loader.class**. The class that the data getting from. That is just example. In my real code the data loaded from csv file. That is not a problem.

```
public class Loader {

private String[] name;
private double[][] value;

public Loader() {
    name = new String[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
    value = new double[][] {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11}, {10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, {13, 14, 15, 16, 17}};
}

public String getTupleName(int index) {
    return name[index];        
}

public double getValue(int indexTuple, int indexAttribute) {
    return value[indexTuple][indexAttribute];
}

public int dataSize() {
    return value.length;
}
}
```

And this is the output

```
inside data.class
A--1.0 3.0 5.0 
B--4.0 6.0 8.0 
C--7.0 9.0 11.0 
D--10.0 12.0 14.0 
E--13.0 15.0 17.0 
in main class
A--13.0 15.0 17.0 
B--13.0 15.0 17.0 
C--13.0 15.0 17.0 
D--13.0 15.0 17.0 
E--13.0 15.0 17.0
```

why the output that printed in method main difference with output that printed inside of Data.class? Why the data changed it self, it must same, help please..

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr. You have a wall of code and can honestly do better paring down the amount of code to the *smallest possible* example that reproduces your problem.

However from the output I can say with almost 99% certainty you are creating a single row instance,  manipulating the values inside it, and adding references to the single row multiple times. Instead you need to make a new object *for each row* and populate them separately. This way each of your A,B,C,D,E rows points to a different row object.

---

The problem you are experiencing can be demonstrated with the following pseudocode:

```
ArrayList<Foo> list = new ArrayList();
Foo aFoo = new Foo();
aFoo.Bar = 2;
list.Add(aFoo);
aFoo.Bar = 3;
list.Add(aFoo);

foreach(x in list):
    print(x);
```

Which will output `3` twice!

Altering this code to the following will fix it:

```
ArrayList<Foo> list = new ArrayList();
Foo aFoo = new Foo();
aFoo.Bar = 2;
list.Add(aFoo);
aFoo = new Foo(); //note we are creating a *new* object here
aFoo.Bar = 3;
list.Add(aFoo);

foreach(x in list):
    print(x);
```

Comment: +1 Simplifying the code to be the minimum to do what you want is likely to show up the bug as well.

Comment: Thanks very much, your explain is usefull, the problem was fixed now

Answer (score 2):

`double[] value` is defined outside the loops hence it's the same array and you overwrite its values in the loop.

Quick fix:

```
for (int i = 0; i < setOfInstance.length; i++) {
    double[] value = new double[attributeIndex.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
        value[j] = loader.getValue(i, attributeIndex.get(j));
    }
    setOfInstance[i] = new Instance(loader.getTupleName(i), value);

    print(i);   //give true output
}
```

Also note that `print(i);` should probably be `print(setOfInstance[i])` in this block